# Amazon Cross-Origin Request Blocked:

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, cors

Our backend is built with Angular 4 and it is deployed on AWS S3 using Serverless. All things are working very well but we have very one small issue. If a custom header is added, it throws warning as follows.

> "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://7uqw9ghjr7.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/uat/user
>   . (Reason: missing token ‘app_version’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel)."
>
> "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://7uqw9ghjr7.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/uat/user
>   . (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)."

The "app_version" is the custom header I added.

If I remove this custom header, all things are working fine.

I would be appreciate any help.

I need to fix this "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" issue and add my custom header.

This is HttpHeader code that is included in every REST API call

```
headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'app_version': '1.0'
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Our backend is built with Angular 4 and it is deployed on AWS S3 using Serverless.": Maybe did you mean the frontend is interacting with some REST API service from your backend (?).

You can clarify a little more your scenario but, based on your last lines: "This is HttpHeader code that is included in every REST API call" I could infer this is classic CORS error when working with API Gateway with Lambda Proxy method, remember that's how Serverless framework works on it by default. Please read: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/

So you always have to return a complete set of your headers in your response, allowing the cross-origin resource sharing:

```
let response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
        //"Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-Requested-With": '*',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Requested-With',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": 'GET, OPTIONS',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true// Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS 
    },
    body: body
}
```

This could result in some tedious task in some cases, so you can check solutions as Middy that works very well: https://github.com/middyjs/middy

Comment: Thanks very much fidelio. I will take a look quickly the github and will back to you soon.

Comment: You should add `app_version` to the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` list since that is the custom header that the error message cites.

Comment: Reading comments below, I understand are you uploading your backend application to the S3 bucket, it is right? If it is, I suggest choosing an EC2 instance for example, or API Gateway + Lambda Function as a "serverless" approach (pretty cool). Remember AWS S3 is a storage service so it can't manage processes, like your backend application needs, only their static content.

Comment: Thanks very much guys. I fixed the issue by set the cors in serverless.yml file as follows. ```cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers:
              - Content-Type,
              - X-Amz-Date
              - Authorization
              - X-Api-Key
              - X-Amz-Security-Token
              - X-Amz-User-Agent
              - app_version
            allowCredentials: false```